# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild') in normal JS Page

Tags: javascript, html

I keep having this error even though i have checked the html 10 times. The aim is that it removes everything on the page and then makes a new div and adds everything. But i keep getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')`.

I have tried things like adding defer to the Js and other things but nothing has worked.

I would be very Thankfull about Help and it might be a stupid mistake. I am a bit new to JS, or in other words i have not done a lot of JS.

```js
var username = "test";
function handleNext() {
  var input = document.getElementById("anmeldenInput");
  var header = document.getElementById("anmeldenH1");
  var image = document.getElementById("anmeldenImg");
  var paragraph = document.getElementById("anmeldenP");
  var link1 = document.getElementById("anmeldenLink1");
  var link2 = document.getElementById("anmeldenLink2");
  var button = document.getElementById("anmeldenButton");
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  div.removeChild(input);
  div.removeChild(header);
  div.removeChild(image);
  div.removeChild(paragraph);
  div.remove(link1);
  div.remove(link2);
  div.removeChild(button);
  document.getElementById("HTMLbody").remove(div);
  var divPassword = document.createElement("div");
  var back = document.createElement("input");
  var inputPassword = document.createElement("input");
  var headerPassword = document.createElement("h1");
  var imagePassword = document.createElement("img");
  var linkPassword = document.createElement("a");
  var paragraphBackPassword = document.createElement("p");
  var paragraphPassword = document.createElement("p");
  var buttonPassword = document.createElement("input");
  imagePassword.src = "";
  imagePassword.alt = "KBW - Logo";
  imagePassword.id = "passwordImg";
  back.onclick = "handleBack()";
  back.id = "back";
  var backArrow = document.createTextNode("<-");
  back.appendChild(backArrow);
  paragraphBackPassword.id = "pBack";
  var displayUsername = document.createTextNode(username);
  paragraphBackPassword.appendChild(displayUsername);
  headerPassword.id = "h1Password";
  var titlePassword = document.createTextNode("Kennwort eingeben");
  headerPassword.appendChild(titlePassword);
  inputPassword.type = "password";
  inputPassword.id = "inputPassword";
  inputPassword.placeholder = "Kennwort";
  linkPassword.href = "https://passwordreset.microsoftonline.com/";
  var linkText = document.createTextNode("Kennwort vergessen");
  linkPassword.appendChild(linkText);
  buttonPassword.type = "button";
  buttonPassword.id = "passwordButton";
  buttonPassword.value = "Anmelden";
  paragraphPassword.id = "pPassword";
  var textP = document.createTextNode(
    "Bitte melden Sie sich beim IT Support, wenn Sie Ihr Passwort vergessen haben."
  );
  paragraphPassword.appendChild(textP);
  divPassword.id = "divPassword";
  divPassword.appendChild(imagePassword);
  divPassword.appendChild(back);
  divPassword.appendChild(paragraphBackPassword);
  divPassword.appendChild(headerPassword);
  divPassword.appendChild(inputPassword);
  divPassword.appendChild(linkPassword);
  divPassword.appendChild(buttonPassword);
  divPassword.appendChild(paragraphBackPassword);
  document.getElementById("HTMLbody").appendChild(divPassword);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title id="title"></title>
  </head>

  <body id="HTMLbody">
    <div id="div">
      <img src="" alt="Microsoft Logo" id="anmeldenImg" />
      <h1 id="anmeldenH1">Anmelden</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="anmeldenInput"
        placeholder="E-Mail, Telefon oder Skype"
      />
      <p id="anmeldenP">
        Kein Konto?
        <a href="https://signup.live.com/" id="anmeldenLink1"
          >Erstellen Sie jetzt eins!</a
        >
      </p>
      <a href="https://support.microsoft.com/" id="anmeldenLink2"
        >Sie können nicht auf Ihr Konto zugreifen?</a
      >
      <input
        type="button"
        id="anmeldenButton"
        value="Weiter"
        onclick="handleNext()"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Please **reduce** the code in the question to a **[mcve]** demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Side note: It's not the problem, but `script` tags must be inside `head` or `body`, they can't be **after** `body`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
document.getElementById("HTMLbody").remove(div);
```

The [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) method on an element removes the element you call it on, not the element you pass in (that would be [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)). So you're removing the `body` element. Later, when you do:

```
document.getElementById("HTMLbody").appendChild(divPassword);
```

...it fails because there's no element with that `id` in the DOM anymore, so `getElementById` returns `null`, and you can't use properties of `null`.

Comment: thx will help allot

Comment: gives me this error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.